# How can I serve static files like swagger ui in Cloud functions

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I serve [swagger-ui-dist](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) in Cloud Function with Go?

Out of Cloud Functions environment I would do:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net/http"
)

func main() {

fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./swagger-ui-dist"))
http.Handle("/swaggerui/", http.StripPrefix("/swaggerui/", fs))

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

But since Cloud functions use a normal function as handler using the Standard http.HanlderFunc interface I don't know how to make it work.

I have tried to simulate this scenario to do my tests with http.ServeFile, but didn't work. Seems like is not downloading all the contents of the folder.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func cloudFunctionHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./swagger-ui-dist")
}
func main() {

    http.HanldeFunc("/swaggerui/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible in three ways (that I know):

1. Serve the static files from a CDN. E.g. from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.40.0/
2. Host the static files yourself on a different endpoint
3. Add the static files to the root folder of your cloud function. These will be packaged together with your code and therefore be available when deployed

(I went for option 3)

For options 2 and 3 you have to override the folder that swaggerui uses for its static assets. How you do this depends on how you configure the swagger ui.

In my case I was using the flask_restx Python package to generate the `swagger.json` and serve the swaggerui. So I monkeypatched like so:

```
from flask_restx.apidoc import apidoc

apidoc.static_folder = '<MY STATIC FOLDER PATH' # e.g. os.path.abspath('static/swaggerui')
```

Also, you need to copy the files from the swaggerui library to your function's root directory before running `gcloud function deploy ...`.

I copy the `static` folder from flask_restx to my function's root directory during my CI pipeline.

Hope this helps anyone!

Comment: you know option 3 is as static as your source code, right?
it gets imported/referenced so it gets compiled into your bundle - for a library or folder of assets, a storage service is needed

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in several way and it worked locally with the same behavior as Cloud Function (same function signature), but it didn't work after deployment on Cloud Functions.

I understood why. In fact [Buildpack (the tools develped by Google for building a container without a Dockerfile, and now in the CNCF sandbox)](https://buildpacks.io/) compiles the .go file and copy the binary to the final container layer. All the other files/directory are omitted. Thus, it can't work!

I recommend you to use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) (same underlying platform as Cloud Functions, and in some cases, cheaper. I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e))

The other solution is to use a not compiled language such as NodeJS or Python.

Comment: Thanks, make sense @guillaume . Great article by the way.

Comment: @Idemas If this has helped, can you please mark the answer as accepted.