# static files handling in cloud functions directly rather than from storage

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, static-files

I am trying to deploy a React app via cloud functions and I want to server the static files.

So basically the root of the structures are :

```
Build/ (which contain React built stuff)
index.js
```

In cloudbuild.yaml last section of deployment I am using handlers but it does not affect of static files

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    handlers:
      - url: /static
        static_dir: build
      - url: /.*
        script: auto
      args: ['functions','deploy','something',...]
```

What I guess is that the functions could not directly do such static files and we must put them in to a bucket. Any idea?

Comment: the handlers are for appengine, you have all mixed here!! Can you clean your question?

Comment: Mr Blaquiere is correct, while [Cloud Functions can be built using Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions) the only thing that applies to the Function you deploy is the arguments you use in `gcloud functions deploy`. IIRC, deploying static content you'd have to make the handlers in the JS code and have them in the root folder, as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), using of static style files . So if you show us your JS code we can help with that. This will also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66045498/15452572